# how to use SUMIF to calculate a cell from the figures in 2 other cells based on the date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup, cell-format

I have one cell that calculates a figure based on 2 cells, so for example target quantity is in C6 then the completed quantity is in D6 so cell E6 is "=D6-C6"  but i only want it to calculate and put a figure into E6 if its after a certain date, if it's not after a certain date i want the cell to remain blank or number 0.
So January won't show anything until the last week in January, then February won't calculate anything until after last week of february or even until 1st March etc then the calculations will stay there for the rest of the year.
This is what i have tried in E6:

=SUMIF(J3,">25/01/2024")=D6-C6

J3 is a cell that i have todays date... =TODAY()  so that i could have it calculate automatically based on the actual date, the 25/01/2024 is just the date i thought i would want the calculation starting.
Its letting me put the formula above in E6 with no errors but instead of calculating D6 mins C6 and giving me the figure in plus or minus, its just showing FALSE.

I'm really stuck on this one if anyone could help and point me in the direction of where i am going wrong please :-)  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `SUMIF`, use `IF`:

```
=IF($J$3-"25/01/2024">0,D6-C6,0)
```

Comment: MGonet,  thank you so much, that worked great.  I  really appreciate your help, thank you :-)